# How to check contain in a string by using LinQ and Lambda?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have two strings.

---

- string A is "HORIDE"
- string B is "TOBRITE"

---

How to check for the vowels 'A, E, I, O, U' in my string and export out in the order they were in the string by LinQ and Lambda.
For example:
the result of string A after the check is 'O I E'

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clarify it?

Comment: What's your expected result?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select words with vowels in List<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862648/select-words-with-vowels-in-listt)

Comment: @Minh what if if a vowel comes two times in string?

Comment: It still export out 2 two times. For Example: "TRABAIGRAN" => "A A I A"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var vowels = new[]{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

var vowelsInWord = "HORIDE".ToCharArray()
    .Join(vowels,
        c => Char.ToUpper(c),
        v => Char.ToUpper(v),
        (_, v) => v);
```

This is the result in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net):

[image: Query result.]

PS: If you want to preserve capitalization from the initial word replace `(_, v) => v` with `(c, _) => c`.

**Edit**

To compare the resulting sequences I suggest you place the code above into an extension method and then use [`SequenceEqual`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal(v=vs.100).aspx) method to compare the results:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> GetVowels(this string value)
{
    var vowels = new[]{'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};
    return value.ToCharArray()
        .Join(vowels,
            c => Char.ToUpper(c),
            v => Char.ToUpper(v),
            (_, v) => v);
}
```

And in your calling method just use:

```
var sameVowels = "HORIDE".GetVowels()
        .SequenceEquals("TOBRITE".GetVowels());
```

Comment: I can not find Join() after ToCharArray()

Comment: add `using System.Linq;` at the top of the file.

Comment: if i want to check if the order results of the two strings are the same or not how do I do that

Comment: @MinhNguyen, unfortunately I did not understand what you want. Can you provide an example?

Comment: Example 1: 
- String A is "HORIDE" => 'O I E'. 
- String B is "TOBRITE" => 'O I E'.
=> true (It have same order).
Example 2:
- String A is "HANEMO" => 'A E O'.
- String B is "TENAMO" => 'E A O'.
=> false (it dont have same order).

Answer (score 0):

It looks you are trying to find vowels that are coming in the word, you can do that this way:

```
Char[] vowels = new Char[] { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u' };

string A = "HORIDE";

var VowelsFound = A.Where(x => vowels.Any(v => Char.ToUpperInvariant(v) == Char.ToUpperInvariant(x))).Distinct();
```

### OUTPUT:

> > O
> >     I
> >     E

[WORKING FIDDLE EXAMPLE](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PagxLe)